# How to define javascript inside directive template

Tags: html, css, angularjs, jquery-tabs, angular-directive

Below is my tabbed window please suggest me where to provide the javascript for the below menu inside the template of the directive.

[image]

below is my directive

```
app.directive('basictabs', function() {
    return {

  restrict: 'AE',
  replace: true,
 template :'<div class="tab-menu">\
     <ul>\
     <li class="unselected"><a href="#">Tab 01</a></li>\
     <li class="selected"><a href="#">Tab 02</a></li>\
     <li class="unselected"><a href="#">Tab 03</a></li>\
     <li class="unselected"><a href="#">Tab 04</a></li>\
     </ul>\
     <div class="tab-content">\
      <div class="tab-01">\
       Content in Tab 01 goes here.\
      </div>\
      <div class="tab-02">\
       Content in Tab 02 goes here.\
      </div>\
      <div class="tab-03">\
       Content in Tab 03 goes here.\
      </div>\
      <div class="tab-04">\
       Content in Tab 04 goes here.\
      </div>\
   </div>\
   </div>'     
  };
});
```

Comment: What do you mean ? What JS do you want to provide ?

Comment: numerous places it could be. Not enough detail given to provide good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Link Function

> We use the link option to create a directive that manipulates the DOM.
>   The link function is optional. If the compile function is defined, it
>   returns the link function; therefore, the compile function will
>   overwrite the link function when both are defined. If our directive is
>   simple and doesn’t require setting any additional options, we may
>   return a function from the factory function (callback function)
>   instead of an object. When doing so, this function will be the link
>   function.

The link function has the following signature:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

// manipulate the DOM in here

}
```

**scope**

The scope to be used by the directive for registering watches from within the directive.

**element**

The *instance element* is the element where the directive is to be used. We should only manipulate children of this element in the postLink function, since the children have already been linked.

**attrs**

The *instance attributes* are a normalized (pascalCased) list of attributes declared on this element and are shared between all directive linking functions. These are passed as `JavaScript` objects.

You can use `JQuery` within the link function for manipulating the `DOM` like as shown in the example

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xy9LM/)**

```
app.directive('basictabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div id="tabs">\
            <ul>\
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>\
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>\
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>\
            </ul>\
            <div id="tabs-1">\
                <p>Content for Tab 1</p>\
            </div>\
            <div id="tabs-2">\
                <p>Content for Tab 2</p>\
            </div>\
            <div id="tabs-3">\
                <p>Content for Tab 3</p>\
            </div>\
          </div>',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            var jqueryElm = $(elm[0]);
            $(jqueryElm).tabs()
        }
    };
})
```